# Install packages satisfying dependencies only in Fedora 20

Tags: fedora

I have a large number of packages which I want to install in Fedora 20. How can I install packages satisfying dependencies only?( I'm not connected to internet while installing)

Answer (score 0):

there is nice yum plugin called download-only.

```
yum -y install yum-downloadonly
```

prepare package target

```
mkdir -p /opt/packages
```

download packages

```
yum install pkg1 pkg2 pkg3 -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=/opt/packages/
```

copy all from `/opt/packages/` to another machine and run

```
yum localinstall ./*rpm
```

in folder with transferred packages.